# Ubuntu installer problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I am fairly new to Ubuntu and I have some problems. My Ubuntu version is 11.10. For some time now, the Ubuntu software center hasn't been working (when I click on it, it lights up a bit, as if it will start, but nothing happens), and installing from the terminal does nothing as well. Whatever I try to install that way, I get the message:

> Reading package lists... Done
>
> Building dependency tree... 0%

And then it kind of freezes.

Both the installer and the software center have been working fine before, but I have no idea when they stopped, or what I did to make them this way... Does anyone have any idea how I can fix them?

Comment: Please, anyone?

Comment: Try http://www.askubuntu.com

Answer (score 0):

If you familiar with the Terminal, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and see what happens or errors. It should update your package list. Apt-get is a command line software center.